# Get file name of the newest log during runtime using logback

Tags: java, logback

Is there a method to get the name of the current file (at runtime) without having to scan folders for the newest log created?

I'm currenty using logback 1.1.1

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, as in general logback can be logging to many files at the same time.  You could create your own appender that saved the file name in a singleton that your app could access.

To do this yourself extend ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender, override openFile(String file_name) and you can get the name of the logfile each time it changes.  Remember to delegate to super.openFile(String file_name), otherwise the file won't actually be opened.

Then in logback.xml change your config to use your own appender.

Comment: Indeed, many logs at the same time would make such feature very unlikely. I didn't thought about that, since I only write small applications logging 1 file at a time. I'll leave the question unanswered tho until a resounding 'no' or 'yes' shows up.

Comment: added more detail to the answer on how to do it yourself.  This question has come up before on the mailing list, and I've not seen a better solution suggested.